# Extra space above and below links in divisions that I can't get rid of?

Tags: html, css, margin

The sidebar menu for my website contains links to three social media websites. When you hover over 'Contacts', these links show up in the drop down box. I have put the links inside their own divisions so I would be able to customize them individually and noticed that no matter what I change, there is extra space in the div as if I had added a margin to the links. I can change the width fine but there is space above and below the text in every box. I want the space gone so the result is just 3 lines of text sitting underneath each other instead of 3 blocks. What have I done wrong? Should I be using something else instead of divisions? Also, I added a pink border to the links to make the extra space more visible.

```css
html {
  background-color: #05061A;
  min-height: 200%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato Bold 700', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7.20vw;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D2DFF0, #7D81BE, #05061A);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D2DFF0, #7D81BE, #05061A);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #D2DFF0, #7D81BE, #05061A);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #D2DFF0, #7D81BE, #05061A);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  padding: none;
  margin: 0%;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  transition: text-shadow 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-stroke-width: 5.3px;
  -webkit-stroke-color: transparent;
  -webkit-fill-color: transparent;
}

h1:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #D2DFF0;
  transition: text-shadow 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-stroke-width: 5.3px;
  -webkit-stroke-color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-fill-color: #FFFFFF;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.60vw;
  color: #7D81BE;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.10s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.10s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.10s;
  -o-transition: color 0.10s;
  transition: color 0.10s;
  padding: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

h3:hover {
  color: #D2DFF0;
}

h4 {
  color: #7D81BE;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

h5 {
  color: #7D81BE;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1vw;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
}

h5:hover {
  color: #D2DFF0;
}

h6 {
  color: #7D81BE;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
}

h7 {
  color: #D2DFF0;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.60vw;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
}

h8 {
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.40vw;
  color: #D2DFF0;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.10s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.10s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.10s;
  -o-transition: color 0.10s;
  transition: color 0.10s;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-left: -10.9%;
  min-width: 15vw;
}

p {
  color: #D2DFF0;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  margin-top: none;
  margin-bottom: none;
}

a {
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #7D81BE;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.10s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.10s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.10s;
  -o-transition: color 0.10s;
  transition: color 0.10s;
}

a:hover {
  color: #D2DFF0;
}

a:visited {
  color: #7D81BE;
}

div {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}

#sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 22%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  top: 6%;
  left: 4%;
  position: fixed;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0C1033, #05061A);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0C1033, #05061A);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0C1033, #05061A);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0C1033, #05061A);
}

#sidebarart {
  padding: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}

#gallery {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 4vw;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.album {
  display: block;
  padding: none;
  margin: 5% 5% 20% 5%;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #05061A;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #05061A;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #05061A;
  transition: box-shadow 0.60s ease;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.album:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #D2DFF0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #D2DFF0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #D2DFF0;
  transition: box-shadow 0.35s ease;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: none;
  margin-bottom: none;
  height: auto;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
}


/* Content inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content {
  float: left;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  margin-top: none;
  margin-bottom: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 10%
}

.link {
  display: block;
  max-width: auto;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  line-height: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>L4-E</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="Izzy Palmer">
  <meta name="description" content="L4-E Music">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Music, L4-E">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="question.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Pontano+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<figure>
  <div class="sidebarbox" id="sidebar">
    <header>
      <a href="index.html">
        <h1>L4-E</h1>
      </a>
    </header>
    <img src="images/Sidebar-art.PNG" id="sidebarart" alt="Sidebar Art"><br>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><h3>Bio</h3></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio.this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this
          is my bio.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><h3>Contacts</h3></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="link">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <h5>Facebook</h5>
          </a>
        </div><br>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <h5>Twitter</h5>
          </a>
        </div><br>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="https://soundcloud.com/l4-e" target="_blank">
            <h5>Soundcloud</h5>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: On Firefox, Chrome and Safari on Mac, there is no space between those links...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem, what you're seeing is the default margin on the `h5`. You've defined `padding: none; margin: none;` which would get rid of that margin... if `none` were a valid value for `margin/padding`, but it isn't, so those lines are being ignored in your stylesheet. Change that to `0` instead. And if you want the links to be right on top of one another, remove the `<br>` and add `clear: left;` to `.link`, and if you want to create vertical space, use `margin` or `padding`. I also removed `line-height: 5%` because that was messing up the element's height and causing the text to stack on top of one another.

```css
html {
  background-color: #05061A;
  min-height: 200%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato Bold 700', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7.20vw;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D2DFF0, #7D81BE, #05061A);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D2DFF0, #7D81BE, #05061A);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #D2DFF0, #7D81BE, #05061A);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #D2DFF0, #7D81BE, #05061A);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  padding: none;
  margin: 0%;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  transition: text-shadow 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-stroke-width: 5.3px;
  -webkit-stroke-color: transparent;
  -webkit-fill-color: transparent;
}

h1:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #D2DFF0;
  transition: text-shadow 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-stroke-width: 5.3px;
  -webkit-stroke-color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-fill-color: #FFFFFF;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.60vw;
  color: #7D81BE;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.10s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.10s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.10s;
  -o-transition: color 0.10s;
  transition: color 0.10s;
  padding: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

h3:hover {
  color: #D2DFF0;
}

h4 {
  color: #7D81BE;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

h5 {
  color: #7D81BE;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h5:hover {
  color: #D2DFF0;
}

h6 {
  color: #7D81BE;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
}

h7 {
  color: #D2DFF0;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.60vw;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
}

h8 {
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.40vw;
  color: #D2DFF0;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.10s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.10s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.10s;
  -o-transition: color 0.10s;
  transition: color 0.10s;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-left: -10.9%;
  min-width: 15vw;
}

p {
  color: #D2DFF0;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  margin-top: none;
  margin-bottom: none;
}

a {
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #7D81BE;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.10s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.10s;
  -ms-transition: color 0.10s;
  -o-transition: color 0.10s;
  transition: color 0.10s;
}

a:hover {
  color: #D2DFF0;
}

a:visited {
  color: #7D81BE;
}

div {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}

#sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 22%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  top: 6%;
  left: 4%;
  position: fixed;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0C1033, #05061A);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0C1033, #05061A);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0C1033, #05061A);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0C1033, #05061A);
}

#sidebarart {
  padding: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}

#gallery {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 4vw;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.album {
  display: block;
  padding: none;
  margin: 5% 5% 20% 5%;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #05061A;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #05061A;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #05061A;
  transition: box-shadow 0.60s ease;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.album:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #D2DFF0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #D2DFF0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 4px #D2DFF0;
  transition: box-shadow 0.35s ease;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: none;
  margin-bottom: none;
  height: auto;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
}


/* Content inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content {
  float: left;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  margin-top: none;
  margin-bottom: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 10%
}

.link {
  display: block;
  max-width: auto;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  /*border: 1px solid pink;*/
  /*line-height: 5%;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>L4-E</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="Izzy Palmer">
  <meta name="description" content="L4-E Music">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Music, L4-E">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="question.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Pontano+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<figure>
  <div class="sidebarbox" id="sidebar">
    <header>
      <a href="index.html">
        <h1>L4-E</h1>
      </a>
    </header>
    <img src="images/Sidebar-art.PNG" id="sidebarart" alt="Sidebar Art"><br>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><h3>Bio</h3></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio.this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this is my bio. this
          is my bio.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><h3>Contacts</h3></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="link">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <h5>Facebook</h5>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <h5>Twitter</h5>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="https://soundcloud.com/l4-e" target="_blank">
            <h5>Soundcloud</h5>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</figure>
```